# Fetch() API not updating JSON file

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a JSON file I want to read from and write to that looks like this:

```
[
    "test@example.com"
]
```

I want to add info to this file using the `fetch()` API. So far, I can only read from this file.

```
let handle = JSON.stringify(`test@example2.com`); // handle is fine irrelevant of "" or ``
const url = `../json/emails.json`; // URL is fine
const options = {
    method: `POST`, // PUT return error at second fetch: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: handle
};

fetch(url) // this fetch is fine
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error getting the stuff`);
        }
        return response;
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(`Data: ` + data);
    });

fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error getting the stuff`);
        }
        return response;
    })
    .then(a => a.json())
    .then(append => {
        console.log(`Data updated: ` + append);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('Request failed: ', err);
    });
```

I get no errors (aside from that `PUT` comment); ESLint and TSLint don't have any problem with the JS file nor with the JSON file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just to clarify - are you trying to update local file with the fetch API?

Comment: Yes. From what @Quentin says, that isn't possible. I'm thinking of translating the above code into Python or using Node.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fetch()` is an API for *making HTTP requests*.

It can't write to files. In particular, nothing can write to arbitrary URLs. (Imagine if it was possible for any browser to write new data to `http://www.google.com/`!)

If you want your PUT or POST request to change data on your server, then you must write *server-side code* to process the request and edit the file.